# An error (Call to a possibly undefined method echo through a reference with static type) when a calling a class method of an object

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a structure with PluginMediator class and ServiceProxy class. They both are within the same namespace and when I am creating an object of the proxy class and try to invoke each of its methods I receive the following error:

> Call to a possibly undefined method echo through a reference with
>   static type

**Fla code**

```
var _proxy:MyServiceProxy = new MyServiceProxy();

// calls MyService to echo a string and return to onHelloResult.
_proxy.echo("Hi", onHelloResult, null);
_proxy.echo("world!", onHelloResult);
```

**MyServiceProxy class**

```
public class MyServiceProxy extends BaseProxy
{
    public function echo(message:String, callback:Function = null, context:Object = null):void 
    {
        callService("echo", [message], callback, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: `_proxy.echo("world!", onHelloResult);</i>`

Is the `</i>` supposed to be there?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Because I am not quite familiar with services and vsphere(flash) sdk, I renamed the class without the word Mediator. Once I returned the word in the name, everything just went fine. For now;)